# Por que não dá segmentation fault quando escrevo num "char *" sem alocar memória?

Tags: c, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória

A minha dúvida é se o compilador aloca automaticamente memória para a variável `s1`

```
char *s1;
char s2[20];

//s1=(char*)malloc (sizeof(char)*20);
s1="palavra1";

strcpy (s2,"palavra2");


printf("s1:%s\ns2:%s\n",s1,s2);
```

Aparentemente se eu fizer a alocação que se encontra em comentário, tem o mesmo `output`, ou seja, a `palavra1` é impressa na mesma.

A mesma situação se passa quando faço o seguinte:

```
char *s1 = "teste";
char s2[20];

//s1=(char*)malloc (sizeof(char)*20);
//s1="palavra1";

strcpy (s2,"palavra2");


printf("s1:%s\ns2:%s\n",s1,s2);
```

Irá imprimir a palavra "teste" e "palavra1"

O que posso concluir daqui?

Comment: Simples, não dá segmentation fault porque não fizeste nada de errado: s1 é um apontador para char e a única coisa que fizeste foi alterar a localização de memória para onde esta a apontar. Ficou a apontar para uma constante (string literal). Isto é válido em C. Se usares a variável APENAS como sendo de leitura, nunca irás ter qualquer problema. O problema só irá surgir se tentares alterar o valor da string, por exemplo: s1[1] = 'X'.
Vê por exemplo esta pergunta no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963780/when-should-i-use-malloc-in-c-and-when-dont-i

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Porque C não obriga alocar memória. A linguagem pode acessar todo seu espaço de endereçamento de forma insegura. C é poderosa, performática e flexível, ao custo da robustez. Se o programador disser que quer acessar uma área da memória, a linguagem deixa. A falha de segmento só ocorrerá se o segmento de memória está protegido para acesso (escrita), o que não é o caso.

Está funcionando o que foi escrito, mas deixará de funcionar o que estava lá na memória anteriormente. Nesse exemplo irá funcionar por que é algo muito simples, em uma aplicação mais complexa provavelmente comprometeria a memória.

Poderia ter pego um endereço fora da área acessível pela aplicação, aí daria erro.

Sem alocar a memória, qual é o valor de `s1`? É o que estava na memória anteriormente. Em C a memória não é limpa na declaração da sua alocação. C apenas reserva um espaço para uso, nesse caso na pilha da aplicação. Essa "sujeira" está dando "sorte" de ser algo que executa. Pode ser que tente mais tarde e já aconteça outra coisa.

Em todas as linguagens não basta testar para saber se está certo. Sim, o teste seria suficiente se realmente fosse possível testar todas as situações possíveis. Mas é virtualmente impossível alguém conseguir fazer isto. Por isto que sempre tem que entender como tudo funciona e saber o que está fazendo. Testar nunca é a solução, teste só prova que funciona em determinada situação, não prova que não funciona. Eu gostaria que todo programador entendesse pelo menos isto.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Em C isso é ainda mais válido.

A conclusão é que esse código está errado, mesmo que ele "passe no teste".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: não estou a ver nada de errado no codigo...  Parece-me que`s1` está sempre inicializado a apontar para zona válida de memória